# Cordova build failed : Could not find support-v4.jar

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, npm, support-v4

I don't know what i did but my build fail until 3 hours on android and I can't fix it ... There is the log :

> ANDROID_HOME=
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is
>   scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action)
>   instead.
>   at.build_bxct3n5fn9ey9qgc57qreulsp.run(C:\Users\User\MyProject\application\platforms\android\build.gradle:143)
>
> The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
>
> Incremental java compilation
>   is an incubating feature.
>
> The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please
>   use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
>
> WARNING: Module
>   'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' depends on one or more Android
>   Libraries but is a jar
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).   Searched in the following
>   >     locations: BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.569 secs
>
> ```
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
> ```
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>     exception.
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).   Searched in the following
>   >     locations:
>   >       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I use (edited :)cordova-android@6.4.0 and cordova 8.1.2(cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: Same here, I guess jcenter.bintray.com could have made some changes that induced this error.

Comment: Ty for reply ! Can we check it somewhere ?

Comment: I have the same error. How can we let people from jcenter.bintray.com to konow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK THEN,
After update my gradle and set the environment variable on Windows 7 of the /bin gradle folder (yes, i didn't), upgraded Android Studio, upgraded Cordova to 8.1.2, do "cordova platform rm android" and "cordova platform add android@6.4.0" on any change i finaly found the issue.

I just uninstalled NDK in SDK Manager. For me it works, i don't know if it is for all but i finaly built my project !

[image]

Sorry for english and ty for reply all

Answer (score 1):

Changing `build.gradle` `repositories` to use maven repository solves this issue:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This file can be found on `platforms/android/build.gradle`.

Comment: @ACES it did work for me. Do you still see the same error, trying to download dependencies from https://jcenter.bintray.com ?

Comment: Ty @a--m, don't know if it working or if i have another issue but my build fail with this message : 
"No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android"
I installed NDK and CMake with Android Studio but it's the same, any idea ? :(

Comment: @JoshuaTorri this should fix the problem described by the OP where the resources load from jcenter fail. You should be seing an error like the one in the question, like: `Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter. ....`. This solution fixed this error.

Comment: Nope @a--m , now i have this error :
BUILD FAILED in 2s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: @JTorri Looks different. Not sure if it could relate somehow, but did not experience this. You may want to check this thread to see if anything helps: https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15